# How do I program a function for stats.binned_statistic that counts the number of values in each bin, without duplicates?

Tags: python

Is there a way to count the number of values in a bin without counting duplicates?  stats.binned_statistic seems to be the most helpful to me, but the only problem is that I can't seem to define a function that returns the proper count of values to me. This is what I have so far:

```
bin_count, bin_edges, bin_number = stats.binned_statistic(time, values,   statistic=lambda y: len(set(y)), bins=range(0, finaltime, 5))
```

and the error appearing is "TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index"

So if I had time = [1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 10] and values = [7, 3, 9, 3, 5, 7, 11, 45], I would like the bin_count to be [4, 3] and not [5,3], which is what the predefined 'count' in this function gives me.

If anyone can help me with my function or perhaps another way to solve this, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You can unique your time array before passing it to binned_statistic.

```
bc,be,bn = binned_statistic(list(set(time)),None,statistic='count',bins=2)
```

Passing callables to binned_statistic never seems to work(try passing statistic=sum and statistic="sum". They should be equivalent, and yet they are not. Strange.).

Try binning your values and dereplicating yourself:

```
dv = numpy.digitize(time,numpy.arange(0,10,5))
udict = {}
udict.update([((dv[i],v),t) for i,(t,v) in enumerate(zip(time,values))])
nv,nt = zip(*[(k[1],udict[k]) for k in udict.keys()])
bc,be,bn = binned_statistic(nt,nv,statistic='count',bins=2)
```

Essentially, pass your values to numpy.digitize, which will assign them each a bin. `enumerate(zip(time,values))` produces a numbered list of time-value pairs, which I rearrange a little bit to build a dictionary keyed by bin-value combinations where the values are the corresponding times. Then retrieving every member of the dictionary will produce a new array of values and times where time-value pairs are unique with respect to values in a specific bin. Then run it through binned_statistic, as per spec.

((This is awfully difficult to read and so on. I welcome superior solutions. Making-unique is tricky to do when you want to retain some other data that can be distinct. ))

Comment: I want the values to be unique though, not the time array.

Comment: You want the `values` to be unique but the bin identities based on `time`?

Comment: yeah exactly! so the bin is based on time, and in each bin, the number of unique values are counted.